# Find the new bisector length form a moved circle chord?

Tags: circles

I have no idea if this is the right forum to ask, but it is a math question. Please let me know where to ask if this is wrong. Sorry.

I have a chord going through a circle and know the length from that chord to the edge of the circle. If I move that chord "up", I need to know how to calculate the new "length" from the chord to the edge of the circle.

I've added an image (I hope it worked)[image]

Comment: It's a less common trigonometric function these days, but that length has a name: [versine](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Versine).

Comment: Move this "chord" up... by how much? The new length is obviously different if you move the chord up by a different amount.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple Pythagoras. If the radius of the circle $(r)$ is known, and the distance from the origin to the chord is known $(h)$, then the length of the chord $(c)$ can be gotten from $\frac{c}{2} = \sqrt{r^2-h^2}$, or $c = 2\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$.

[image: Chord from Pythagoras]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the radius or know the dostsnce of origin to the chord.